# Dual booting XP and 18.04 - missing Windows root>\system32\hal.dll - how to fix please

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-xp

My machine is a Dell Precision Workstation-380, with Pentium (r)4,  Ubuntu is 18.04 LTS. When starting the option to select either Win XP or Ubuntu appears, but if I choose Win XP I get the message: Missing file Windows root>\system32\hal.dll

Both Win XP and Ubuntu are on the same 232Gb HDD and used to work until a few years ago. I would like to reduce the large partition containing Win XP and increase the Ubuntu partition which is nearly full, but GParted will not permit this while the HDD is mounted.

Even if I could find a way to delete the Win XP partition, I would be reluctant to do so in case there are files in addition to the OS in the partition.

Would a Grub repair attempt (using any Ubuntu boot disc) be wise? Or should I seek a way to add the missing file somewhere else via Terminal?

All advice welcome.

Keep safe.

Comment: Assuming your Ubuntu works, can you mount the partition containing Windows XP? If you can then you can browse the partition for any files you might want to keep. If you want to resize the partitions you need to boot from a live usb/cd and make the changes from the live session. It’s always advisable to backup any important data before doing this. If you want to fix Windows XP then google search “Hal.dll”, there are plenty of hits on Windows support forums.

Comment: Thanks PonJar; in GParted the mount option for the Win XP partition is greyed out unfortunately. I have been using Ubuntu Backups daily but I think this captures only the Ubuntu files. I am currently trying Hirens Boot CD and will let you know how I get on.  Fingers crossed!

Comment: Is your XP partition formatted with NTFS? If so have you got the NTFS driver installed in Ubuntu? You can install it with “sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g“. Alternatively if it’s FAT you may need the driver for that. I think it’s in the latest kernels but not sure if it’s provided in 18.04

Comment: Thanks again PonJar. Googling "Ha.dll" etc led me to Hirens. My experiment with Hirens Boot CD failed (I could not get it to run beyond the opening screen when choosing the Win XP loading option at boot), but that may be related to my uncertainties when extracting an .iso folder and copying to a DVD-RW. I probably used the NTFS format for the Win XP partition - I think the capacity of Fat32 (4Gb?) would have been too small. I used Terminal to add "sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g" successfully but the Win XP partition mount option is still not apparent. So, no harm done, but no progress either.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the partition containing XP from the terminal? Assuming your system has a /mnt directory then “ sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt” should do the trick. Change the x and the n to match your XP partition. eg sda2. The lsblk command should help you work out what  it should be. Then use your file manager to navigate to /mnt. It should show you XP partition

Comment: Great idea, although I think once mounted the partition would not be resizeable.  First attempt produced no change.  Second attempt  produced message in Terminal "Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.  The volume may be already mounted or another software may use it which could be identified by the help of  the "fuser" command". I have a screenshot but don't know how to add it to this dialogue.

Comment: The suggestion to try to mount the partition was to make it possible to recover any data that you might want to keep. Once that is achieved you would need to un-mount the partition to resize it. Please add any new information to the original question as an edit. Hopefully we can get you fixed :)

Comment: OK.  Right now GParted shows that the Win partition is mounted - thank you! The flag is "Boot".  So how can I browse the contents of the partition please?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the file manager. It probably opens in your /home location. You want to find a location that is usually called “computer”. That’s the / location. /mnt is a directory under that where you should find the root of your Windows C: drive. This assumes you mounted to /mnt

Comment: I tired searching for the key words of "computer" and "mnt" without success.  However, in file manager I found a folder of "other locations" which included a Windows folder containing the following:  /bin
/boot
/cdrom
/dev
/etc
/home
/lib
/lost+found
/media
/mnt
/opt
/proc
/root
/run
/sbin
/snap
/srv
/sys
/tmp
/usr
/var
/.cache
/initrd.img
/initrd.img.old
/vmlinuz
/vmlinuz.old

Comment: Drill down into the /mnt folder from that list

Comment: I treid searching for the key words of "computer" and "mnt" without success.  However, in file manager I found a folder of "other locations" which included a Windows folder containing /mnt - hooray! I can now trawl for recognisable folder and file names and possibly copy/ save them before deleting the partition.  I'll report how I get on with moving stuff.

Comment: Well, i've got 80Gb of stuff including the Win XP OS on the Win XP partition  (discovered thanks to your patience and efforts), and < 1Gb left on  my Ubuntu partition.  Moving documents to the Ubuntu partition works but is rather a slow process. I'd quite like to copy the lot and at least keep it as an archive.  Perhaps I should add a second IDE drive or USB stick next and leave the machine to get on with it? Then I would need to ask again for help with re-balancing the space on the adjacent Win XP and Ubuntu partitions or deleting the Win XP partition and re-allocating the space to Ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds like you need some extra space to back up the XP partition. You can shrink the XP partition and grow the Ubuntu partition using a live disk/usb but that is not without risk, so best make a backup first. It might be helpful to run “df -h” in a terminal to see disk sizes and usage. If you have a spare disk that is large enough you can copy and paste the entire partition with GParted

Comment: I agree. So my next challenge will be to mount and format as NTFS an old disc which has been used for backing up 2 Apple laptops.  This may cause me to seek help via a new query.

Thanks again PonJar. As a matter of interest, how goes the COVID-19 battle in your location? Good luck!
Regards
Henry
Stroud, UK

Comment: If you use GParted you only need to make unformated space the same as or larger than your XP partition. As far as COVID-19 goes I am retired and staying in except for food, click and collect. Getting no end of diy done (usually look after grandchildren). Take care. John, Brighton UK.